# TypeORM generating strange 'versionless' UUID

Tags: uuid, typeorm

I'm using this in an entity definition:

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
Id: string;
```

and getting UUIDs like:

```
C17D188A-E91E-EC11-AAF7-0AB75295BBB4
```

In terms of the first character of the 3rd group of characters here, `'E'` - this sould be UUID v14 - which doesn't exist? How does TypeORM generate a UUID?

Comment: Do they all happen to be v14? Or does the version appear to change from one UUID to another? Might be an endianness problem with generation or display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question, TypeORM leverages a RFC4122 compliant UUID v4 generator to generate a string for `uuid`-type columns, [as seen here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a868078f8f4f63cc8d81a63e098d639ed12c6608/src/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.ts#L535).

Regardless, the `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')` decorator maps the column to a `uuid` database field type if the database supports it. It could be that your database engine is most likely not generating `uuidv4`-compliant UUIDs.